# In Ionic 2, how to float an element above the keyboard when the keyboard shows?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I want my message input bar to float above the keyboard when the keyboard shows but it looks like there's no [keyboard-attach directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Keyboard/) ([like v1](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/keyboardAttach/)) in Ionic 2 yet ([maybe in the works](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5536)?). Is there any alternative/workaround?

Current behaviour:

[image][image]

Wanted behaviour:

[image]

Here's the code of my message input bar:

```
<ion-toolbar position="bottom" *ngIf="userIsAdmin">

    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" class="message-form">

        <ion-badge class="message-form-badge">Admin</ion-badge>

        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Type a message..." ngControl="messageInput"></ion-input>

        <button type="submit" small class="message-form-button">Send <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon></button>

    </form>

</ion-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a solution which works for me on IOS.

When you inspect the `<ion-item>` with `<ion-input>` in the browser(debugging use Safari for IOS) you can find that ionic generates a `<div class='input-cover'>` which has the style `position: absolute;`.

Write a CSS which overrides this as below

```
.input-cover {
  position: static;
}
```

This did the trick for me and now when you focus on an input field, it scrolls into view and does not hide below the keyboard anymore and all this works buttery smooth.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy. Great, easy solution.

Comment: Answer worked like a charm, have been struggling with plugins etc .. Great job!

Comment: Good job on finding this workaround but the ion-item isn't needed. @Master_A2Z this issue is not present on Android. I've tested this override on Android and it doesn't seem to break anything so all good I guess.

Comment: Great solution, without this. Really a lot of work needs to be done.

Comment: This does absolutely nothing for me. Furthermore, I don't see `input-cover` being added anywhere.

Comment: How did you inspect that? Do you know how to do that on Ionic 3?

Comment: This did not work for me, anyone here found any alternative ?

Answer (score 5):

I've also needed to implement this. I did it and it works perfectly.

1st you need to use cordova plugins keyboard, and at the start call 
`cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` so the keyboard will not push your view up.
2nd you need to listen on keyboardshow and keyboard hide events like this with a the handlers:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
                    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', this.dispatchMe);
                    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', this.dispatchMeHide);

    dispatchMe(e) {
        var event = new CustomEvent('keyboardShown');
        event['keyboardHeight'] = e.keyboardHeight;
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    dispatchMeHide() {
        var event = new CustomEvent('keyboardShown');
        event['closed'] = true;
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
```

Than you can make an observable from event like this:

```
this.keyboardObservable = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyboardShown');
```

Than you can listen to that observable. If the keyboard is open than you change the height of the container where your messages are shown. You basically have to make it lower for the height of the keyboard. Here is how I did that

```
this.chatService.keyboardObservable
            .subscribe(data => {
                if (data.closed) {
                    this.sectionHeight = 85 + '%';
                    this.inputBottom = 0 + '%';
                }
                else {
                    this.docHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
                    this.sectionHeight = ((this.docHeight - data.keyboardHeight - (document.getElementById('toptoolbar').clientHeight + document.getElementById('inputchat').clientHeight)) / this.docHeight) * 100 + '%';
                    this.inputBottom = data.keyboardHeight / this.docHeight * 100 + '%';
                }

            });
```

and you change these properties with ngStyle like this

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': sectionHeight}"
```

I also needed this for chatapp, and now it works perfectly (even if you rotate the screen portrait/landscape mode), the input always floats above the keyboard just like in the native apps :)

I hope this will help you!

Comment: You can also shorten this and emit directly into the handlers instead of dispatching custom events and having an observable which listenes to them. Probably you can create observables directly from the "native.keyboardshow" event and cut this code by 2/3 :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up using and one that I'm satisfied with is:

1. Removing `Keyboard.disableScroll(true);`
2. Using a regular `<input type="text">` instead of `<ion-input type="text">`

Works perfectly now!

Comment: It just worked when switched to pure html input element

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with Android, so I created a service method that I could put into individual components. It's based on using `<ion-input>` fields inside of an `<ion-content>` tag.

This takes advantage of the `setScrollTop` method that was added to the `Content` class.

## Service

```
export class KeyboardService {

    autoKeyboardScroll(content:Content, scrollBackAfterKeyboardClose?:boolean) {
        if (!content) {
            return;
        }
        var previousScrollTop = null;
        function onKeyboardShow(e) {
            // if the content no longer exists, stop the listener
            if (removeListenersForMissingContent()) {
                return;
            }
            previousScrollTop = content.getScrollTop();
            // find the input that's currently in focus
            var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
            if (focusedElement && ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(focusedElement.tagName)!==-1) {
                // determine the total offset between the top of the "ion-content" and this element.
                // we will do this by climbing up the dom until we reach the "ion-content"
                var offsetTop = focusedElement.offsetTop + focusedElement.scrollHeight;
                var parentEl = focusedElement.offsetParent;
                while (parentEl && parentEl.tagName!=='ION-CONTENT') {
                    offsetTop += parentEl.offsetTop;
                    parentEl = parentEl.offsetParent;
                }
                // we want to move the input so that the bottom of the focused input is just above the keyboard
                var contentDimensions = content.getContentDimensions();
                var newScrollTop = offsetTop - (contentDimensions.contentHeight - focusedElement.scrollHeight);
                content.setScrollTop(newScrollTop);
            }
        }
        function onKeyboardHide(e) {
            // if the content no longer exists, stop the listener
            if (removeListenersForMissingContent()) {
                return;
            }
            // set the scroll top back to the initial position, if requested
            if (scrollBackAfterKeyboardClose) {
                content.setScrollTop(previousScrollTop);
            }
        }
        function removeListenersForMissingContent() {
            // if there is no content, remove the keyboard listeners
            if (!content || content.getContentDimensions().contentHeight===0) {
                window.removeEventListener('native.keyboardshow', onKeyboardShow);
                window.removeEventListener('native.keyboardhide', onKeyboardHide);
                return true;
            }
        }
        // setup listeners
        window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', onKeyboardShow);
        window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', onKeyboardHide);
    }
}
```

## Component

```
@Component({
    template: `<ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <div style="height: 400px"></div>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 1</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 2</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 3</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 4</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 5</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Field 6</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>`
})
export class MyPage {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    constructor(private: keyboardService: KeyboardService) {}

    // add the keyboard scroll action to this page. this is added after the view has been created,
    // so the content element will be avaialble.
    ionViewDidEnter() {

        // timeout seems to be required, to ensure that the content child is available
        setTimeout(() => {
            // set the keyboard to auto-scroll to the focused input, when it opens
            this.keyboardService.autoKeyboardScroll(this.content);
        });
    }
}
```