# Keyboard and Ionic view problems in ios

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic-view

input field in middle,and when i click to field input password. i got like this.
[using ionic view app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMEdE.jpg)

this my code in app.component.ts.

```
if(this.platform.is('ios')) { Keyboard.disableScroll(true); }
```

and app,module.ts

```
platforms: { ios: { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false } }
```

i build in linux debin.

```
:~/:ionic info
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.8
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

respect for all answer.
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ionic 2, how to float an element above the keyboard when the keyboard shows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706398/in-ionic-2-how-to-float-an-element-above-the-keyboard-when-the-keyboard-shows)

Comment: @Alberick0 its different dude. this work well in ios if we build.
just get like above in ionic view.
bug in ionic view, i just don't know to fix it.