# Ionic 3 ion-input captures focus of the whole row in Android

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

This ionic page is just a form with some elements. In the Phone field, I have created a modal that opens when you click on an image:

[image: Field]

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
   <ion-col>
    <form #registerForm="ngForm" novalidate [formGroup]="form">    

      [...]

      <ion-item>
        <img item-left margin-left src={{flagPath}} (click)="presentCountryModal()">
        <p item-left (click)="presentCountryModal()">+{{countryCode}}</p>
        <ion-icon item-left name="arrow-dropdown" (click)="presentCountryModal()">
        </ion-icon>

        <ion-input
          placeholder="Phone"
          type="text"
          [(ngModel)]="account.phone" 
          name="phone"
          required
          pattern=".{8,}"
          #phone="ngModel"
          ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

It works perfectly on iOS and Windows on ionic-lab. But in Android the behavior is different: when I click on the image, the Phone ion-input gets the focus and the whole form moves up, making space for the keyboard and hiding the field under the header.

I'd like to:

1) Be able to make the image clickable.

2) Disable the automatic scrolling when an ion-input gets focused. I've tried `keyboard.disableScroll(true)` with no success.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786672/1839990), adding `.input-cover { position: static; }` to the scss files stabilizes the form and makes the image click event responsive! So that solves the first question.

But I still have the problem that, when the keyboard opens, the whole page moves up and the top elements hide below the header (and you can't scroll them down).

Comment: For 1) you may try by creating a row with two separate columns, one for the flag and the other for the input. For 2), please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161705/ionic-2-form-goes-up-when-keyboard-shows/41163695#41163695).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a what it looks like a working solution for the first problem! Sebaferreras, I've tried what it's explained in that post, but I don't notice any change when I change keyboard.disableScroll between true and false.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to make a separated `ion-item` form the `img`. If you have an `ion-input` inside an `ion-item`, everything you put together will be "part" of that `input`.

2) The easiest way to do this without manipulating via ts is using a regular input, not the `ion-input` or using the `ion-input` inside a `div` instead of the `ion-item`. The second one i'm just guesing, since the behaviour of the scroll for showing the keyboard happens if you have an `ion-input` inside `ion-item`.

Hope this helps :)